# Define a hook for embedded model in loopback

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs

Can I create a hook for an embedded model in loopback?

I have these two models (I'm using MongoDB):

**Student**

```
{
  "name": "student",
  "plural": "students",
  "base": "User",
  "idInjection": false,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {},
  "relations": {
    "pass": {
      "type": "embedsOne",
      "model": "pass",
      "property": "mypass",
      "options": {
        "validate": true,
        "forceId": false
      }
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

**Pass**

```
{
    "name": "pass",
    "base": "Model",
    "idInjection": false,
    "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
    },
    "properties": {
        "expiredDate": {
            "type": "date",
            "required": true
        }
    },
    "validations": [],
    "relations": {},
    "acls": [],
    "methods": {}
}
```

I tried to define a hook in this way but no log in console.

**pass.js**

```
 module.exports = function(Pass) {

        Pass.observe('before save', function(ctx, next){
            console.log("test");
        });
 }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post here the code that is using `pass.js` please ?

Comment: @Phan sorry for my bad answer

Comment: @EbrahimPasbani thanks for tryring